# Include IP header in payload of ICMP request using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, icmp

Currently trying to send some test ICMP packets using scapy, but cannot seem to figure out how to include a payload in the ICMP header. Specifically, I am testing a time exceeded error, here is my code:

I have tried looking extensively online for documentation regarding this, but to no avail.

```
send(IP(dst="123.123.0.1",src="123.123.0.0")/ICMP(type=11))
```

(ignore ips)

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `IP(...)/ICMP(...)/b"a blob of crunchy data"` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can send a payload by stacking it after `ICMP()` layer

```
send(IP(dst="123.123.0.1", src="123.123.0.0") / ICMP() / b"payload")
```